# How to detect if ruby code is invoked via Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote a small .rb tool that used the "blank?" method. I want my program to continue to work if invoked directly by ruby. I Monkey Patched Object with code below but I don't want to monkey patch when running under Rails. What can I do?

```
class Object
  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? (respond_to?(:strip) ? strip.empty? : !!empty?) : !self
  end
end
```

Comment: Unless your rails project loads this file, it should not get evaluated when Rails boots.  Where does this "program" live?

Comment: Also WHY do you need this monkey patch? It's pretty far-reaching.

Comment: It is a library / tool. I need this monkey patch when invoked directly using ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to keep in mind is that monkey-patching a class directly — that is, opening a class to define a new method — is discouraged. It works, but it's not very flexible and it's considered a code smell.

A more sensible approach to monkey-patching is to define your methods in a mixin and then including it in a class.

This also allows you to conditionally include the mixin. For example, a common requirement in Ruby Gems is to only implement or define something if another library is (already) loaded. A common way to do this is to check if a constant from that library is defined. For example, in your case you could do this:

```
module PresenceExtensions
  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? (respond_to?(:strip) ? strip.empty? : !!empty?) : !self
  end
end

unless Module.const_defined?("Rails") || Object.method_defined?(:blank?)
  Object.include PresenceExtensions
end
```

Another common technique is to try to load a gem and then add your alternative monkey-patch only if the gem is not available:

```
begin
  require "active_support/core_ext/object/blank"
rescue LoadError
  Object.include PresenceExtensions
end
```

This technique has the advantage that will tell you immediately if the gem is not available, so that you don't have to worry about load order.

Answer (score 0):

Rails by default should not load a file at runtime unless it is expected to through some kind of configuration either by default or an initializer etc.  If this class definition just sits inside your `lib/monkey.rb` for example, Rails won't auto-load it unless you tell it to.

You can test this out in your rails console if you are using `pry`.

Just do:

```
rails c
# inside your console:
show-method Object.blank?
# this should show you the actual method definition which should be somthing
# like:
From: /Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb @ line 16:
Owner: Object
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 3

def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
end
```

But if rails had loaded your lib file, you would see instead that definition which you can force in the console with `require`

```
require './lib/monkey.rb'
show-method Object.blank?

From: /Users/myself/some/rails/project/lib/monkey.rb @ line 2:
Owner: Object
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 4

def blank?
  puts "this is a monkey patch"
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? (respond_to?(:strip) ? strip.empty? : !!empty?) : !self
end
```